# what's the syntax for if the image exists get the image?

Tags: php, loop, images, search

I want this to display images instead of posts. What would be the syntax for replacing posts with the images on my site? My code currently says while have post then show the post. I want it to be while have image then show image

```
        <?php if (have_posts()) : global $loop_view; ?>

        <?php get_template_part('loop-actions'); ?>

        <div class="loop-content switchable-view <?php echo $loop_view; ?>" data-view="<?php echo $loop_view; ?>">
            <div class="nag cf">
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    get_template_part('item-video');
                endwhile; ?>

            </div>
        </div><!-- end .loop-content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear if you want to show one image or all image for each post. If you want to show just one, I'd use the post thumbnail:

- Check for a post thumbnail. If there's a post thumbnail - output it (for simplicity I'm assuming you'd output it in a new template part; you could simply include it inline using `the_post_thumbnail()`);
- Otherwise include the post as currently (or a placeholder image if you'd prefer).

`if(get_post_thumbnail_id()):
      get_template_part('item-image-only');
    else:
    // fallback 
    endif;`

If you need to output all images, you can use `get_children` - e.g. :

`$attached_images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID ,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order') );`

(and you can then check if an item has images by checking `count($attached_images)`)

Comment: Thank you! I want to output all images, where exactly would I put get_children into my code?